# Switching from CMS to G1 garbage collector

Tags: java, garbage-collection

As of Java 8, is G1 a better garbage collector than CMS? Is it advisable to make the switch? What kinds of tuning and testing is needed for such a switch?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> As of Java 8, is G1 a better garbage collector than CMS?

Possibly depending on your use case and requirements.  In Java 9, G1 will be the default.  Whether this is a good idea is a matter of opinion.

> Is it advisable to make the switch?

Not unless you have a reason to do so.

> What kinds of tuning and testing is needed for such a switch?

I would look to your standard load and stress testing you do now.  If you don't have such tests, I would write some to reflect what is important to your application.

In terms of tuning, there is lots of options, which ones are best will depend on your use case.